# using diff and -y limitation on number of characters displayed

Tags: bash, diff

I have these 2 files file1.txt:

```
$ cat file1.txt
I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples.
I need to run the laundry.
I need to wash the dog.
I need to get the car detailed.
```

and file2.txt:

```
$ cat file2.txt
I need to buy apples.
I need to do the laundry.
I need to wash the car.
I need to get the dog detailed.
```

I want to see the out difference in files using the `diff` command and display it using the `-y` option.

```
$ diff -y file1.txt file2.txt
I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy app | I need to buy apples.
I need to run the laundry.                                    | I need to do the laundry.
I need to wash the dog.                                       | I need to wash the car.
I need to get the car detailed.                               | I need to get the dog detailed.
```

but there seems to be a limitation in the number of characters that can be displayed. Note line1 from file1.txt.

**Is there a way this limitation can be increased so show the full line content?**

```
$ echo I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy app | wc
      1      15      62
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to specify the width, try this:

```
diff --width=250 -y file1 file2
```

man diff:

> -W NUM  --width=NUM
>                 Output at most NUM (default 130) print columns.

Comment: tks, i did see that but...tks...anyhow this might be a simple one for you. I would like to know how many characters(including spaces) is in the the longest line in the file1.txt?I have tried `wc -L file1.txt` but that does seem to include spaces?

Comment: that does include the space. you can compare the result with `diff ... | sed 's/ //g' `, which remove all spaces in the file.